# How to control location of drop down menu in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to change the way that the dropdown menu in Tkinter seems to render. I found this code on TutorialsPoint:

```
    from Tkinter import *


    def donothing():
        filewin = Toplevel(root)
        button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
        button.pack()


    root = Tk()
    menubar = Menu(root)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=donothing)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing)

    filemenu.add_separator()

    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)
    editmenu.add_separator()

    editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=donothing)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=donothing)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=donothing)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=donothing)
    editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=donothing)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
    helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)
    root.mainloop()
```

According the site the menu that renders should look like this: [Dropdown Menu Image Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvQXc.jpg)

However when I run the program on my computer what I see is this: [Dropdown Menu Image Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNmjo.png)

Is there any way for me to force the behaviour shown in the version on the web, where every dropdown menu extends from the left corner of the menu button to the right instead of from the right corner of the menu button to the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this has something to do with the settings on your computer and not tkinter/Python.

It works like TutorialsPoint's on my computer just fine!
[image]

Something to keep in mind though... (Maybe this applies?) Depending on where your window with the drop-down IS, the orientation of the drop-down changes (This is my window near the edge of my monitor)

[image]

If I had duel-monitors I'd test that as well.  Hopefully this helps .

Comment: You are indeed correct. I got an Ubuntu distribution to test with and it does render as shown on the site. I am testing/developing on Windows 8 (unfortunately) and I have no idea why it would act that way. In either case, it sounds like it is out of my control. Thank you for the response!

Comment: I literally opened an answer about this same thing on windows 10 with me developing a tkinter app. Same issue. Told that it was local problem and not tkinter python. I think this is a bug on windows 10 or it could be because of dual monitors. I have dual monitors as well. Hmmmmm worth looking into.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be pretty annoyed at this bug if it happened to me :\

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on my Desktop Windows 8.1 system.

I fixed it by

1. Going to Control Panel, Tablet PC Settings
2. Clicking on the Other tab and setting Handedness option to Left-handed
3. clicking the Apply button.

See this link for more information: https://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-menu-position-from-left-to-right-in-windows-vista/